# Django Admin Tabularinline with Auto complete field

Tags: python, jquery, django

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to implement an auto-complete field in a tabular inline model. Where a user selects a site and the address cell is consequently filled with the appropriate address I defined my fields in a form as below:

```
self.fields['sites'].widget = forms.Select(
  attrs = {
    'id': 'id_sites',
    'onchange': 'getsiteaddress(this.value)',
    'style': 'width:200px'
  },
  choices = sites_list,
)

self.fields['site_address'].widget = forms.TextInput(
  attrs = {
    'id': 'id_siteaddress',
    'style': 'width:200px'
  }
)
```

Everything works fine for the first row. My issue is that when I move to the second row of the inline model and select an address the cell of the first row is the one that changes. How can I call the second row?

This is my jQuery function

```
function getsiteaddress(site) {
  let $ = django.jQuery;

  $.get('/Delivery/deploymentsite/'+ site, function(resp) {
    $('#id_siteaddress').val(resp.data)
  });
}
```

any help is really appreciated

Comment: From the behaviour it sounds like you're repeating the same `id` on multiple elements, when they should be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: Also note your JS is missing a closing `'` - as you can see in the syntax highlighting in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply can you please explain more what do you mean by using classes

Comment: Use the `class` attribute in your HTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class